# Range slider value not going back to starting value

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $('#slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        value: 100,
            slide: function (ev, ui) {

                var total = ui.value;
                $('#slider').not(this).each(function () {
                    total += $(this).slider('value');
                })
                if (total < 100) {
                    return false;
                }
                $( ".order" ).html(total);

            }

        });
    });
</script> 



<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="cal_table">
    <table style="text-align: left;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Orders      :<span style="text-align: right" class="order">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

I am making a range slider with a start limit from 100. When the page is loaded, it works as it should but when I slide back from increased value back to 100, the values are random(close to 100.eg, 103,132,110). It depends on the speed I slide. It never goes back to 100 unless I slide it back down very slowly.

Comment: maby `total <= 100`

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour. You can specify the value of `step`. For instance, if you set `step=5`. This will always move 5 steps on sliding. Also if you want slider to start from 100. Please set the `min=100`. For your problem, You can do the following:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $('#slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        value: 100,
            slide: function (ev, ui) {

                var total = ui.value;
                if (total < 100){
                  //This will set the slider to 100 again if user will slide it less than 100
                   $("#slider").slider('value',100);
                   $("#slider").trigger('change');
                   return false;
                }

                $('#slider').not(this).each(function () {
                    total += $(this).slider('value');
                });

                $( ".order" ).html(total);

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to lock the HTML Range Slider not to go down under 100 just like I did on jQuery Slider.

Comment: yes by specifying `min=100`. The slider would start from 100. and it cannot be slided less than 100

Comment: Sorry if I don't clarify this, What I want is, I want the slider to be long just like 0 - 1000 But I don't want my users to be able to slide down under 100.Slider head should stuck at 100 when user is trying to slide down lower than 100. It shouldn't go down under 100.